# Customize v-select dropdown position

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify v-select component. The issue I am facing is instead of opening the dropdown downwards, I want it to open upwards because the dropdown is at the bottom of the page so some of the dropdown items don't appear. Like in the picture below there are multiple options are Nunavut which don't appear. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
<v-layout row wrap>
 <v-flex md6 xs12>
  <v-select
   :items="states"
   :closeOnSelect="true"
   multiple
   attach
   item-text='name'
   item-value='id'
  ></v-select>
 </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

Comment: could you make the page bigger, add `mr-8` class to the `v-layout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem by adding **auto**

```
<v-layout row wrap>
 <v-flex md6 xs12>
  <v-select
   :items="states"
   :closeOnSelect="true"
   multiple
   attach
   item-text='name'
   item-value='id'
   auto
  ></v-select>
 </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use `menu-props` see [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#custom-menu-props)

```
<v-select
 :items="states"
 :closeOnSelect="true"
 multiple
 attach
 :menu-props="{ top: true, offsetY: true }"
 item-text='name'
 item-value='id'
></v-select>
```

Comment: it didnt work. no change. Still opens the same way. I don't think that v-select supports menu-props

Comment: it should, what version of vuetify do you have?

Comment: vuetify version 1.0.5

Comment: can you upgrade to a newer version?

Comment: No I can't. alot of my code is dependent on this version.

Comment: Also works with Vuetify v1.5.24 (maybe even older, but did not check that)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is by setting menu-props to auto:

```
<v-select
     :items="states"
     :closeOnSelect="true"
     multiple
     attach
     :menu-props="auto"
     item-text='name'
     item-value='id'
    ></v-select>
```